# Highest value of max_connections in AWS RDS micro instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Currently, the value for the `max_connections` parameter in a MySQL RDS t1.micro server model is `{DBInstanceClassMemory/12582880}` is 32.

Since my server does not allowing any more connections after 32, what is the Maximum safe value for `max_connections` I can use for a micro instance ?

Comment: For reference the AWS RDS product documentation is available at http://awsdocs.s3.amazonaws.com/RDS/latest/rds-ug.pdf

Answer (score 33, accepted):

About 2 years ago, I was tasked with evaluating Amazon RDS for MySQL. I wrote some posts in the DBA StackExchange about my findings and observations:

- `Jul 25, 2012` : [Scaling Percona datacenters: setup and replication](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21491/scaling-percona-datacenters-setup-and-replication/21498#21498)
- `Aug 02, 2012` : [Local database vs Amazon RDS](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21914/local-database-vs-amazon-rds/21919#21919)
- `Sep 21, 2012` : [MySQL 5.5 Runs Out of Memory, Drops All Connections When Creating Many Databases](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24643/mysql-5-5-runs-out-of-memory-drops-all-connections-when-creating-many-databases/24661#24661)

In short, there are three options you cannot alter

- [**max_connections**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections) (per Server Model)
- [**innodb_buffer_pool_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size) (per Server Model)
- [**innodb_log_file_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_file_size) (all Server Models, `128M`)

Here is the Chart I made telling you those per-Server Model limits

```
MODEL      max_connections innodb_buffer_pool_size
---------  --------------- -----------------------
t1.micro   34                326107136 (  311M)
m1-small   125              1179648000 ( 1125M,  1.097G)
m1-large   623              5882511360 ( 5610M,  5.479G)
m1-xlarge  1263            11922309120 (11370M, 11.103G)
m2-xlarge  1441            13605273600 (12975M, 12.671G)
m2-2xlarge 2900            27367833600 (26100M, 25.488G)
m2-4xlarge 5816            54892953600 (52350M, 51.123G)
```

As for your actual question, `t1.micro` has 34 as a [**max_connections**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections) setting. If you cannot surpass 32, that is quite understandable. Amazon AWS must be able to connect to and monitor things for the RDS Instance as a [**SUPER**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_super) user. Not being able to go beyond 32 is reasonable for a `t1.micro` instance. In light of this, you will have no choice but to trust the management scheme administered by Amazon for apportioning [**max_connections**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections) and other options among all MySQL Instances in the AWS Cloud.

Comment: Nice answer. but I thought I can change it in custom Parameter group. So there is no other way than increasing Instance size?

Comment: Only those 3 options are immutable for the sake of the fair distribution CPU cycles, Memory, and Overall Performance to all running MySQL RDS instances.

Comment: All the links are helpful. you saved a day for me

Comment: To check your max_connections, try this command: select @@max_connections;

Comment: See my answer below http://serverfault.com/a/740138/104677

Answer (score 15):

Here's what you can do to change `max_connections` or any other parameter in an AWS RDS (mysql) instance:

- From RDS console go to **Parameter Groups**
- Create a new parameter group based on the default group and name it `my-param-group`
- Modify `max_connections` or other parameters in `my-param-group`
- Go back to instance main page and click **Modify** in **Instance Action** button to modify the instance
- Choose `my-param-group` as the **DB Parameter Group**
- Reboot your instance
- Done!

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer now

Answer (score 9):

It appears that things have changed since the accepted answer.  After seeing this [thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=116213) I ran a test on a db.m3.medium RDS MySQL instance with max_connection manually set to 2000 using DB Parameter Groups.  I was able to create 2000 connections and only then got the expected error of Too Many Connections.